# lattice FPGA internal oscillator simulation issues

Tags: fpga, modelsim

I'm trying to simulate ICE5LP1K FPGA internal oscillator on ModelSim. My design includes the following instance:

```
SB_HFOSC OSCInst1 (
  .CLKHFEN(1'b1),
  .CLKHFPU(1'b1),
  .CLKHF(CLKLF)
)
```

I included sb_ice_syn.v file but have a design loading error:

> Error: ../testbench/sb_ice_syn.v(26066): Module 'SB_HFOSC_CORE' is not defined

I'm not able to find SB_HFOSC_CORE module in the lattice installation folder.
Where can I find the missed modules?

Answer (score 0):

Doing ModelSim simulation of a Lattice ICE40 family (ICE5LP1K device) design with PLLs requires that a Verilog model of the PLL is included.  This is described in Lattice Application Note AN006 (see "c:\lscc\iCEcube2.2015.04\doc\Modelsim_AN006.pdf" for latest iCEcube2 version) on page 9:

> If your design contains PLL, add ABIPTBS8.v and ABIWTCZ4.v in $INST_DIR/verilog. For performing Post-Synth simulation for a VHDL design having PLL, you will require a mixed-language simulator, since the PLL model (ABIPTBS8.v) is available only in verilog format.
>   If the design contains Hardened IP primitives, add the encrypted Verilog simulation library sb_ice_ipenc_modelsim.v available in $INST_DIR/Verilog.

An alternative is if you write a simple simulation model of the `SB_HFOSC_CORE` PLL core, and then include this in the simulation, since I assume that your focus is on verification of the remaining design, so you probably only need the PLL to give a usable clock.

Comment: Actually I'm doing all necessary steps but still unsuccessful.
I added sb_ice_syn.v file, where is defined the HFOSC module. But the HFOSC module has an instance named "SB_HFOSC_CORE" and I'm not able to find any module declaration for the "SB_HFOSC_CORE" instance.

Comment: Maybe Lattice support can help then, since it may be a bug, or for a work-around make a simulation model of the `SB_HFOSC_CORE` PLL core if that will be enough for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It is working now. 
I found the missing module in the sb_ice_ipenc_modelsim.v