# Lattice ICE5LP4K FPGA: How to add HFOSC to user vhdl

Tags: fpga, synthesis, lattice-diamond

I'm having trouble using the internal oscillator for the Lattice ICE5LP4K.  Per the iCE40 Oscillator Usage Guide Appendix, the code in verilog should look like this:

```
    SB_HFOSC OSCInst0 (
       .CLKHF_EN(ENCLKHF),
       .CLKHF_PU(CLKHF_POWERUP),
       .CLKHF(CLKHF)
     ) /* synthesis ROUTE_THROUGH_FABRIC= [0|1] */;
     Defparam OSCInst0.CLKHF_DIV = 2’b00;
```

The code base I'm working from is in VHDL, so I've added the component to my architecture as follows:

```
  SB_HFOSC : OscInst0
    port map(
        CLKHF_EN  => RST_SYS_N;
        CLKHF_PU  => RST_SYS_N;
        CLKHF     => HFOSC_CLK_48MHZ
    );
```

When I tried this, I received errors related to the component SB_HFOSC not being defined.  Then I found this article: [lattice FPGA internal oscillator simulation issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524308/lattice-fpga-internal-oscillator-simulation-issues/32526454#32526454) which mentions adding lattice components to your project file.

I added a new file in my project which contains the following code from sb_ice_syn_vital.vhd:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
---         SB_HFOSC        -------
------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.Vital_Primitives.all;
use IEEE.VITAL_Timing.all;
entity  SB_HFOSC  is 
    generic( CLKHF_DIV: string:="0b00";
                Xon   : boolean := true;
                MsgOn : boolean := true;
                tipd_CLKHFEN: VitalDelayType01 := (0.000 ns, 0.000 ns);
                tipd_CLKHFPU: VitalDelayType01 := (0.000 ns, 0.000 ns);
                tpd_CLKHFEN_CLKHF : VitalDelayType01 := (0.000 ns, 0.000 ns);
                tpd_CLKHFPU_CLKHF : VitalDelayType01 := (0.000 ns, 0.000 ns)
); 
port(
    CLKHF : out std_logic;
    CLKHFEN  :in std_logic;
    CLKHFPU : in std_logic
    );
        attribute VITAL_LEVEL0 of               
    SB_HFOSC  : entity is true;
end SB_HFOSC ;

architecture SB_HFOSC_V of SB_HFOSC is
attribute VITAL_LEVEL0 of
    SB_HFOSC_V : architecture is true;
    signal CLKHFEN_ipd: std_ulogic := 'X';
    signal CLKHFPU_ipd: std_ulogic := 'X';
    signal CLKHF_sig  : std_ulogic  :='X';

component SB_HFOSC_CORE                 
generic( CLKHF_DIV: string:="0b00");    
port ( 
    CLKHF_PU : IN std_logic;
    CLKHF_EN : IN std_logic;
    CLKHF : OUT std_logic
);

end component;

begin
WireDelay : block
  begin
    VitalWireDelay (CLKHFEN_ipd, CLKHFEN, tipd_CLKHFEN);
    VitalWireDelay (CLKHFPU_ipd, CLKHFPU, tipd_CLKHFPU);
  end block;

LS: SB_HFOSC_CORE                    
GENERIC MAP (CLKHF_DIV => CLKHF_DIV)
port map(
    CLKHF_PU=> CLKHFPU_ipd,
    CLKHF_EN=> CLKHFEN,
    CLKHF=> CLKHF_sig
        );
VITALPathDelay :process (CLKHFEN_ipd,CLKHF_sig,CLKHFPU_ipd)
variable CLKHF_GlitchData : VitalGlitchDataType;  
variable CLKHF_zd  : std_ulogic :='X';
begin  
    CLKHF_zd:=CLKHF_sig;
VitalPathDelay01 (
      OutSignal                 => CLKHF,
      GlitchData                => CLKHF_GlitchData,
      OutSignalName             => "CLKHF",
      OutTemp                   => CLKHF_zd,
      Paths                     => (--0 =>(CLKHFEN_ipd'last_event, tpd_CLKHFEN_CLKHF, true),
                                    0 =>(CLKHFPU_ipd'last_event, tpd_CLKHFPU_CLKHF, true)),
      Mode                      => VitalTransport,
      Xon                       => Xon,
      MsgOn                     => MsgOn,
      MsgSeverity               => warning);
end process;

end     SB_HFOSC_V;
```

I also added the component definition (to my top architecture) from vcomponent_vital.vhd:

```
component SB_HFOSC  is 
    generic( 
        CLKHF_DIV: string:="0b00";
        Xon   : boolean := true;
        MsgOn : boolean := true;
        tipd_CLKHFEN: VitalDelayType01 := (0.000 ns, 0.000 ns);
        tipd_CLKHFPU: VitalDelayType01 := (0.000 ns, 0.000 ns);
        tpd_CLKHFEN_CLKHF : VitalDelayType01 := (0.000 ns, 0.000 ns);
        tpd_CLKHFPU_CLKHF : VitalDelayType01 := (0.000 ns, 0.000 ns)
        ); 
    port(
        CLKHF : out std_logic;
        CLKHFEN  :in std_logic;
            CLKHFPU : in std_logic
        );
end  component;
```

When I try to synthesize the code, I receive a slew of errors, all of which appear to be related to "vitaldelaytype01" and "vital_level0" not being defined.  As you can see in the code above, I have included the IEEE Vital libraries.  I tried compiling using the built-in ICECube2 compiler as well as Synplify Pro but receive similar errors in each case.

Am I following the correct process to implement the HFOSC in my code?  Do I need to download additional libraries that aren't automatically provided in the ICECube2 suite?

Comment: I've searched through the iCEcube2.2017.08/LSE directory and found timing_p.vhd which defines the VITAL_Timing package as well as the VitalDelayType01 that is needed.  Why isn't this being found by the tool when it synthesizes the code?  Is it possible that the tool is using a compiled version of the library which excluded the Vital_timing package from the build?

Comment: Did you ever succeed at this?  I have found zero VHDL projects under iCECube2 that use hard IP.

Comment: I have successfully instantiated the SB_HFOSC by adding the component definition to my library, but with the VITAL lines commented out.  Synthesis warns that ROUTE_THROUGH_FABRIC doesn't exist and gets set to default 0, but that's fine for my purposes.

I have a support request in to Lattice asking why the VITAL libraries aren't being read.  (This is on iCE40UL)

Comment: See my answer to this question.  Adding this to your project is an option, but I don't think it is the correct solution.  Let me know if the steps I listed in my answer work for you!

Comment: https://www.latticesemi.com/-/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/TechnicalBriefs/SBTICETechnologyLibrary201504.ashx?document_id=51074

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue through Lattice's customer support portal.  The proper process for instantiating a lattice HFOSC IP block is as follows:

In your library includes:

```
library ice;
```

In your component definitions:

```
component SB_HFOSC  
GENERIC( CLKHF_DIV :string :="0b00");
PORT(
        CLKHFEN: IN STD_LOGIC ;
        CLKHFPU: IN STD_LOGIC;
        CLKHF:OUT STD_LOGIC
        );
END COMPONENT;
```

In your instance instantiations:

```
   u_osc : SB_HFOSC
    GENERIC MAP(CLKHF_DIV =>"0b00")
    port map(
        CLKHFEN  => RST_SYS_N,
        CLKHFPU  => RST_SYS_N,
       CLKHF     => HFOSC_CLK_48MHZ
   );
```

Take note of the pin names - they are different from the Lattice guides which is why I was having issues instantiating the component.

One other interesting thing I learned in the process was that the HFOSC block uses a global buffer, but the Lattice tool doesn't recognize that up front so it can run into issues during post-synthesis P&R.  To reserve one of the 8 buffers for the HFOSC component, limit the total global buffers to 7 as follows (insert into your top level architecture definition):

```
attribute syn_global_buffers : integer;
attribute syn_global_buffers of struct : architecture is 7;
```

Hope this helps others!

Rob

Answer (score 4):

iCEcube2 (2017.08.27940) obviously isn't ready to VHDL out of the package with the "Lattice LSE Synthesis" tool.

This is due to components defined in VERILOG and VHDL doesn't see those at synth stage unless you [re]define the components manually in VHDL. There is a VHDL package file containing them, but I find bugs in it.

Here is what I do:

-Add this file to your project:

```
<"icecube_installation_path">\LSE\userware\NT\SYNTHESIS_HEADERS\sb_ice40_components_syn.vhd
```

-Fix the bug in it; edit the attribute ROUTE_THROUGH_FABRIC to use string type instead of boolean, and "1"/"0" instead of true/false where it is used. Not doing this will fail P&R, but will pass synthesis.

-Now you can add work library to the top of your code and instantiate like normal:

```
library work;
use work.components.all;
--your code here--
osc:SB_HFOSC
generic map
(
  CLKHF_DIV     =>"0b10"    --12Mhz
)
port map
(
  CLKHFEN   =>'1',
  CLKHFPU   =>'1',
  CLKHF =>clk
);
```

This seems to work with my stuff.

Alternatively, using the onboard "Synplify Pro" synthesis tool, I had some success if I added

```
library sb_ice40_components_syn;
use sb_ice40_components_syn.components.all;
```

to the top, but I had severe issues with resetting state machines, so I gave up on it. I simply don't understand how to reset one-hot code state machines without an internal system level global set/reset available. The docs claim its there, but I cant find any clear docs how to use it, at least not for iCE40UL.